# google map directions api for maneuver

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am working on google maps in a flutter. For directions, I am using the direction API. I have to show the exact steps(icons/directions) from point A to Point B to the user. I am getting the maneuver in the JSON response, but I want to show the icons to the user, I didn't see any icons in the JSON response. So, my question is, do I have to design the icons separately and then use the maneuver element to decide which icon to display, or is there any way where I can get these icons from API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Directions API does not return icons for the manuevers, so you should implement your own logic to display them.
Below some icon resources:

- https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/tree/master/src/client/images/directions
- https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=turn

Comment: appreciated. got it.